# Function in which elements are pushed in an array using for-loop; returns empty array while shows expected array in console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, return, push

```js
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let sorted_arr = [];
    for(x in nums){
        if(!sorted_arr.includes(nums[x]))
            sorted_arr.push(nums[x])
    }
    console.log( sorted_arr)
    return sorted_arr
};

const result = removeDuplicates([1,1,2]);
console.log("result", result);
```

> I/P: [1,1,2]
> O/P: [ ]
> stdout: [1,2]

Description:
I am trying to create a function which returns a sorted array of numbers with no duplicates. I have created an empty array "sorted_arr" and iterate the "nums" array in which I push a number in the "sorted_arr" if the number is not already present in it.
The issue I am facing is when I am returning the "sorted_arr" outside for-loop it is empty; while in console.log, i am getting the the expected result.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Are you invoking it properly?

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) And the name `sorted_arr` is misleading, it's not sorted.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. If you are trying to access sorted_arr outside the function you will not be able to. 'let' and 'const' are block scoped.

Comment: SO what is the real code?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue about the outer logic of your application. When I try the code you gave, I get the correct result.

```js
const removeDuplicates = nums => {
  let sorted_arr = [];
  for (const num of nums) {
    if (!sorted_arr.includes(num))
      sorted_arr.push(num)
  }
  console.log(`Stdout: [${sorted_arr}]`)
  return sorted_arr
};

const input = [1, 1, 2];

console.log(`Output: [${removeDuplicates(input)}]`)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use `for/of` loop.  Below is detailed explanation for the same

- `for` - loops through a block of code a number of times.
- `for/in` - loops through the properties of an object.
- `for/of` - loops through the values of an iterable object.
- `while` - loops through a block of code while a specified condition is true.